# index.handler is undefined or not exported AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a index.js and the handler function is defined. But when I test I get the error `index.handler is undefined or not exported`.  Any idea how to resolve this?

[image]

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: fa81b4c8-23f6-4f15-899b-dfc680ae9c57 Version: $LATEST
2021-10-29T08:47:21.477Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.HandlerNotFound","errorMessage":"index.handler is undefined or not exported","stack":["Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
2021-10-29T08:47:22.789Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.HandlerNotFound","errorMessage":"index.handler is undefined or not exported","stack":["Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
END RequestId: fa81b4c8-23f6-4f15-899b-dfc680ae9c57
REPORT RequestId: fa81b4c8-23f6-4f15-899b-dfc680ae9c57  Duration: 1463.33 ms    Billed Duration: 1464 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 11 MB  
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.HandlerNotFound

Request ID
fa81b4c8-23f6-4f15-899b-dfc680ae9c57
```

Answer (score 1):

Lambda functions do not yet support ES6 style (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)

You should use:

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
}
```